# Next.js not parsing package name

Tags: firebase, next.js, yarnpkg

After opening a project I haven't touched for a long while, this error happened.
What could cause Next.js to not parse package names properly? Currently it seems like it only happens for this one module and not anything else.

Using yarn 2, hence the `.zip` you see.

```
error - unhandledRejection: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'firebase' imported from C:\...\.next\server\pages\_app.js
Did you mean to import firebase-npm-9.6.2-5174ad75cc-ed79a1d8fe.zip/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js?
```

Comment: `yarn add firebase`?

Comment: It is there in package.json and have done yarn remove and yarn add for good measure

Comment: Can you show us how are you importing `firebase` in `_app.js`? Also, which version of `firebase` are you using?

Comment: It was `import { getApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';` Version I tried "firebase": "9.0.0-beta.7", and latest

Answer (score 0):

Problem seem to have been resolved by deleting all yarn and Next cache files and reinstalling.